# lambda expression of main function's return value

Tags: lambda, return-value, lambda-calculus

In specific case, like this

```
f(x) { return x+5; } 
g(x, y) { return 2*x + y; } 
main() { return f(g(1, 2)); }
```

what is the lambda expression of return value of function main?

Comment: What does this have to do with lambda calculus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python:

```
lambda x, y: (2*x + y) + 5
```

returns 9 if called with 1, 2.